# Dynamic pointcut expression in aspectj/spring aop

Tags: spring, dynamic, annotations, spring-aop

I want to create a pointcut expression which is dynamic in nature.
I have three packages -
package1,
package2,
common

common should always be inculded and based on system property i want to load package1 OR package2 at any given time

Something like below

```
private static final String PACKAGE = System.getProperty("packagePrefix");

@Around("execution(* "+PACKAGE+"..*.*(..)) && execution(* ..common.*(..))")
```

how can i achieve this?

**EDIT:**

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/780775/2362960) which is quite interesting and i guess will solve my requirement but not able to get it working 
So this link says to have like below

```
@Aspect
public abstract class MyAspect {

protected abstract pointcut();


@Before("pointcut()")
public void myAdviceMethod() {
// Advice code goes here
 }
 }


 public class ConcreteAspect extends MyAspect {

 @Pointcut("execution(* com.acme.*.*(..))")
   protected pointcut() {
  )
 }
```

Included below in my Java config

```
@Bean
public ConcreteAspect myAspect() {
    return new ConcreteAspect();
}
```

But getting below error :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 can't find referenced
>   pointcut pointcut

I guess at run time its not able to find out overriden pointcut method and hence not able to resolve pointcut.
Any idea how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You could use an if() clause to make a check like this:

```
aspect X {
  before(): execution(* Code.*(..)) &&
    if(isOfInterest(thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature().getDeclaringType())) {
   System.out.println("advice running");
  }

  public static boolean isOfInterest(Class s) {
    return s.getPackage().toString().startsWith(packagePrefix);
  }
}
```

I think something similar will work for annotation style syntax. But this approach will include a runtime test at every matched join point.

Comment: Thanks Andy for response.But i guess if() can only be used if I have to enable-disable an advice. So in my case I have to create two advices - one for package1 and one for package2. So if i have 50packages I have to create 50 advices. What i really want is to replace the package name in expression at run time.

Comment: You can replace the implementation of the `isOfInterest` method with whatever logic you find appropriate, but remember, there's a very small cost to pay for evaluating the boolean method at every join point you advise. If your advised code is not invoked many times or it's not performance critical, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Nándor Előd Fekete - I cannot put any logic in isOfInterest because it can only return boolean.From doc - The if(...) body can be any valid Java boolean expression, and can use any exposed formal, as well as the join point forms thisJoinPoint, thisJoinPointStaticPart and thisJoinPointEnclosingStaticPart .

Comment: You can put any logic inside `isOfInterest`, you just need to return a boolean value. The return value of that method will be used in the `if()` pointcut expression to decide if the advice will be run or not.

Comment: @Nándor Előd Fekete- Yes correct but thats not what i want. For my case advice will be enabled for both cases(package1 and package2) its just i want to refer that particular package in my pointcut expression.So e.g - if my process is running which involves package1 the pointcut expression should be applied on package1 not package2 and vice versa. in both cases advice remains same.This could only work if i create two separate advices and enable/disable them like i mentioned on Andy Clement comment above

Comment: What you want is so unclear, nobody can really help you. Don't describe it with words, but with code.

Comment: It depends on what your 'switch' is. How do you determine if you want it to be package1 or package2? Is it what you pass on the command line to the compiler? The if() clauses gives you a lot of flexibility: return s.getPackage().toString().startsWith("package"+System.getProperty("interestingPackage"));  - it just isn't clear how you want to choose whether it is package1 or 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use within, which will scan the given packages

@Pointcut("within(*..common..*(..)")
public void CommonPackage(){}

@Pointcut("within(*..PACKAGE..*(..)")
public void specificPackage(){}

And using @Around/@Before or any advice as u require for your situation
@Around("execution(CommonPackage()&&SpecificPackage()")
Writing the pointcut expression for the different packages and binding them together. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Sharmila for your response. But how will this PACKAGE will be placed in your second pointcut ? Remember PACKAGE is string which gets value at runtime from system property